# Convert a HTML file to Image in C++ apart from 'wkhtmltoimage'

Tags: html, c++, image

I need to convert a local HTML file to a Jpeg Image in a C++ module. As per our requirement, I cannot use 'wkhtmltoimage'. Hence I need any command line tool or libraries( which can be used in C++ ) that are available for the same. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: you could ues mshtml.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick is able to convert HTML to images (by first converting the HTML into PostScript and then to an image), however it's definitely not the best solution. WebKit is really the best tool for the job here. I don't know all the details about your situation, but maybe try linking to WebKit and using it directly instead of invoking wkhtmltoimage?